# Spring WebFlux Functional Endpoint ServerResponse.body causes pipeline to run twice

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I have the following code that is printing 2 and 4 twice

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<?> myRouter() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/server-response-testt"), (request) -> {
            final Mono<String> s = Mono.just(1)
                    .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println(value))
                    .flatMap(exists -> {
                        System.out.println("----------------- 2 -----------------");
                        if (exists % 2 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("----------------- 3 -----------------");
                            return Mono.just("A");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("----------------- 4 -----------------");
                            return Mono.just("B");
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(c ->  {
                        System.out.println("C");
                        return Mono.just("C");
                    });

            return s.flatMap(hasElement -> ServerResponse.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(s, String.class));
        });
    }
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

I expected to only print 2 and 4 once.

If I instead of using ServerResponse from functional endpoints, use the ResponseEntity like the following code, I only get print 2 and 4 once:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getResponseEntity() {
        System.out.println("aqui");
        final Mono<String> s = Mono.just(1)
                .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println(value))
                .flatMap(exists -> {
                    System.out.println("----------------- 2 -----------------");
                    if (exists % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("----------------- 3 -----------------");
                        return Mono.just("A");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("----------------- 4 -----------------");
                        return Mono.just("B");
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(c ->  {
                    System.out.println("C");
                    return Mono.just("C");
                });

        return s.flatMap(b -> {
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityMono = ResponseEntity.ok().body(b);
            return Mono.just(responseEntityMono);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Because in your first case, you return a pipeline that uses `s`, and inside it, you ask ServerResponse to call it once more to get the body. By default, cold publishers are re-executed anytime they're subscribed to. You should do `return s.map(value -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(value));`